# Using NULL in Azure ADF Dynamic content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Hi I am new to Azure ADF and trying to copy additional column values to a table. While doing so sometimes I am getting NULL values from source but while adding that to destination table I get following error.

ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value '' for column name 'clearingHouseContactTelephoneNumber' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'Decimal' (precision:10, scale:0). Additional info: The input wasn't in a correct format.

I want to make sure if there is an empty field then I need to simply add NULL value to that field. However 'NULL' keyword is not acceptable in dynamic content. Please take a look at this example screenshot. [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BAF8.png)

Please help me with adding NULL value to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce function and pass your dynamic value as first parameter and  **null** as second parameter, this function will return the first not null value.

[image]

Comment: I get this error with coalesce function - ErrorCode=TypeConversionFailure,Exception occurred when converting value 'coalesce(activity('Lookup1').output.value[int(variables('i'))].eftEnrollmentUniqueIdentifier, null)' for column name 'eftEnrollmentUniqueIdentifier' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'Decimal' (precision:18, scale:0). Additional info: The input wasn't in a correct format.

Comment: Try this:
coalesce(string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[int(variables('i'))].eftEnrollmentUniqueIdentifier), null)

Answer (score 0):

Using NULL in Azure ADF Dynamic content
Using NULL in Azure ADF Dynamic content

I tried to reproduce the error with similar dynamic content in copy activity and got similar error.

[image]

The reason of this error is the conversion of the string data type to decimal datatype.

The workaround is to using `DataFlow`: If your data flow contains numerous data fields, you must create new columns or modify current ones using the derived column transformation.

For more details, refer  [Derived column transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column).

You can even refer to this Microsoft Q&A post for more insights:  [Copy Task failure because of conversion failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401569/copy-task-failure-because-of-conversion-failure.html)

follow below steps:

- Create a data flow add your source to the dataset then create the derived column to get values from your expression.
  [image]
- for derived column expression create a string parameter.
  [image]
- Go back to pipeline click on dataflow under parameter you can see your parameter for the value select pipeline expression for this parameter and add your dynamic expression
  [image]
- And now, run the pipeline.